# How do I assemble a Dynacam Flycam 5000 (AKA ProAim Flycam)?

Tags: video

I bought the Dynacam Flycam 5000 (also sold as ProAim Flycam, and probably some other no-name brands) in a local shop the other month. Unfortunately no assembly instructions at all were included so I have some troubles getting it setup.

More specifically I need to connect the upper part with the weights.

On the plate holding the weights there are a rubber detail.

The lower part of the camera base and handle is way too large to fit the rubber part on the weight plate.

I'm also left with some metal tubing that I guess should be used to connect these parts.

Any help in putting this thing together would be appreciated.

I have found [a Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHV68vN6DTU) with a time lapse of assembly of this very product. Unfortunately the level of detail is far from helpful since you can't actually tell how these parts are connected.